# Bootstrap drop down is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

Here is the plunker link
http://plnkr.co/edit/0plBF1duKmZoCPFINwPf?p=preview

And here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Looks like I need both

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Not sure why we need the first one though!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you supplied works fine as long as the correct files are linked. I'm not seeing the link for the bootstrap.min.js on your plunker.
Here is a fiddle with the dropdown working just fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/xkL15guj/

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<span class="caret"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Look here! http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: That helped. Thanks!

Looks like I need both
`<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`
and
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">`
Not sure why we need the first one though!?

Comment: Hey @user369217 bootstrap.min.js contains all of the javascript you need to get the dropdowns, accordions etc. to function and the bootstrap.min.css contains the css to make it all look purdy! :)